# Not able to get Recipients(Contact) record of ListEmail

Tags: apex

How to get the Recipients List of ListEmail record? tried with ListEmailIndividualRecipient object, it is returning a blank list and unable to get Contacts or Recipients of ListEmail.

Basically in My Apex code, I am going to query ListEmailIndividualRecipient Standard object.

[image]

Below is my query:

**SELECT Id FROM ListEmailIndividualRecipient**

The issue, I am facing here is, this query always gives a null list.

Please help.

Steps, I am following below:

I have sent an email by using SendListEmail Button on the List Email object.
And it successfully sent an email. Please look into the below screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/361829/edit) your question to also add information about what you have attempted so far (e.g., share any code - even if it did not work). *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include ...(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.")*

Comment: Hi, @Moonpie I have updated my Question. Please look into it again. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to reiterate @moonp

Comment: Are you running that query in Developer Console or within your Apex code? If within Apex, please do as I originally requested and share your code - including class definition.

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Hi, @Moonpie, I am running code in the developer console. I have added some screenshots for clarification that how I am going. Please look into this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Moonpie here is the link, someone asks this in the salesforce forum as well. I am facing the same issue. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000BlxTQAS

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you a specific answer without APEX code as @Moonpie has suggested. 
 *Generally* your query needs context... ListEmailIndividualRecipient is a one-to-many relationship to the ListEmail table, basically, you will not get meaningful data to ask for all the recipients forever.

The pseudo code below will get you started, or post code, please

```
SELECT Id FROM ListEmailIndividualRecipient WHERE ListEmailId = :ListEmailYouWorkingWith.Id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have run the same query. But it gives me a null value.

Comment: sorry, can't help more without code.

Comment: Hi @dbwood, I have updated my question and added some screenshots. Hope this will help you to understand my issue. Thanks.

Comment: there's no need for more code! it's a simple soql query returning no results!